# Properly extending the User Entity in Hibernate5

Tags: java, hibernate, spring-data-jpa, jhipster

I'm upgrading a JHipster app written using Hibernate4 to Hibernate5.

The Hibernate4 version has been running in production just fine, but I want to upgrade to a much newer version of Spring Boot which means also Hibernate5.

I'm running into some query issues with Hibernate5 and would appreciate some extra eyes to confirm I've got the tables updated properly with correct Hibernate syntax.

```
// base Entity
@Entity
@Table(name = "jhi_user")
public class User extends AbstractAuditingEntity implements Serializable {
  // default JHipster generated attributes
}

// additional User attributes
@Entity
public class Foo extends User {
  // some extra attributes, but no "Id" field since it extends User
  
  private String attribute1;
  private String attribute2;
}

// another Entity inheriting from Foo
@Entity
public class Bar extends Foo {
   private String attribute3;
   private String attribute4;
}
```

When I'm trying to use the `UserRepository` to find the `User` account for authentication, I'm getting a lot of grief from Hibernate. I think this relationship structure is no longer valid for Hibernate5, but not sure what to do.

Update: I did locate this article - https://www.jhipster.tech/tips/022_tip_registering_user_with_additional_information.html

Update #2: The author of that article actually put a sample project together which I'm linking for anyone else finding themselves down this rabbit hole.
https://github.com/Paul-Etienne/jhipster-userextra-example - however it's missing a few key pieces (IMHO) such as updating the UserExtra.phone field. which repository do I find the User from to reference the other?

Update #3: Although I know of `@MappedSuperClass`, it's not an option in my specific case, as I'm working with a database that already persists the base object's data.

Update #4: If versions are a "thing" here, I'm running `Spring Boot 2.2.7.RELEASE` and `Hibernate 5.4.15.Final`

I'm experimenting down this path, but it's really causing a lot of refactoring pain, so I'll look at any other viable option.

Comment: done - hope that helps

Comment: thanks again - yes I have. Versions updated in the question. :bow:

Comment: Well, your problem is not related to jhipster indeed, it's about hibernate + spring data jpa. Don't try to follow what you found about JHipster. because your app lives ont its own now. Your 2 other entities Foo and Bar have no table annotation, so could you explicit which inheritance mapping strategy you chose. You said you work with a legacy db schema but you don't give any details about it. Did you follow the upgrade instructions (if any) from Hibernate and Spring Boot?